# What should go in a COUNT (*) OVER window function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I'm looking at an Oracle stored procedure which as the following (paraphrased) sql

```
select AB.*, count(*) over (PARTITION BY 
    TO_CHAR(AB.CAN_DATE,'MONTH'),
    TO_CHAR(AB.CAN_DATE,'MM'),
    'XMEG'
    ORDER BY
TO_CHAR(AB.CAN_DATE,'MONTH'),
    TO_CHAR(AB.CAN_DATE,'MM'),
    'XMEG') from mytable AB;
```

Apparently this code works OK, but I have several questions

1. surely the to_char (...MM) is redundant, as the to_char(....Month) will do the same job?
2. what is the value of an order by clause in a COUNT(*) OVER?  Does it have any effect?  Why is it allowed.
3. what does it mean to include a constant ('XMEG') in the partition / order by.  I'm guessing it will have no effect?

Comment: "...surely the to_char (...MM) is redundant..." -- We don't know. What do you want to achieve? Please post a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: All 3 of your points are valid criticisms of this terrible code.

Comment: For point 2 it has no effect on the `count(*)`, but the query also selects all table fields (`select AB.*, ...`), so it can make sense to have an order clause

Comment: I think you are spot on. This query smells of somebody copy/pasting their way to something that worked without really understanding any of it. But it's always good practice to regression test changes, fix the query to something that makes sense and make sure you still get the same result as the production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will count the values for each month regardless of year. So all the values in October will be counted together regardless of whether it was October 2023, October 1900 or October 9999. If you want the count for individual months then you should use `TRUNC(ab.can-date, 'MM')` or `TO_CHAR(ab.can_date, 'YYYY-MM')` rather than `TO_CHAR` with just the month.

> 1. surely the to_char (...MM) is redundant, as the to_char(....Month) will do the same job?

- `TO_CHAR(AB.CAN_DATE,'MONTH')` finds the name of the month
- `TO_CHAR(AB.CAN_DATE,'MM')` finds the number of the month

Since both are unique to the month then they will have the same effect in the `PARTITION BY` clause and, yes, the second one is redundant.

> 2. what is the value of an order by clause in a COUNT(*) OVER? Does it have any effect? Why is it allowed.

If you wanted a cumulative (running) total starting from the earliest date to the last date then you could use an `ORDER BY` clause. If you do not have an `ORDER BY` clause then the count will be the total over the entire partition.

For example, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (dt) AS
  SELECT DATE '1900-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '1970-10-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-10-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-10-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-10-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-10-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '9999-10-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-12-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT dt,
       TO_CHAR(dt, 'MONTH') AS month_name,
       TO_CHAR(dt, 'MM') AS month_number,
       COUNT(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(dt, 'MONTH')) AS total_by_name,
       COUNT(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(dt, 'MM')) AS total_by_number,
       COUNT(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(dt, 'MM')) AS total_by_month,
       COUNT(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(dt, 'MONTH') ORDER BY dt)
         AS running_total_by_name
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

| DT | MONTH_NAME | MONTH_NUMBER | TOTAL_BY_NAME | TOTAL_BY_NUMBER | TOTAL_BY_MONTH | RUNNING_TOTAL_BY_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-31 00:00:00 | DECEMBER | 12 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1900-10-01 00:00:00 | OCTOBER | 10 | 8 | 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 1970-10-31 00:00:00 | OCTOBER | 10 | 8 | 8 | 1 | 2 |
| 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | OCTOBER | 10 | 8 | 8 | 5 | 3 |
| 2023-10-05 00:00:00 | OCTOBER | 10 | 8 | 8 | 5 | 4 |
| 2023-10-13 00:00:00 | OCTOBER | 10 | 8 | 8 | 5 | 6 |
| 2023-10-13 00:00:00 | OCTOBER | 10 | 8 | 8 | 5 | 6 |
| 2023-10-28 00:00:00 | OCTOBER | 10 | 8 | 8 | 5 | 7 |
| 9999-10-31 00:00:00 | OCTOBER | 10 | 8 | 8 | 1 | 8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kW29wMmK)

And you can see that the final column has a running total (where values with the same `ORDER BY` are counted together).

In your case, the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses are identical so every value in a partition will have the same value and will be ordered identically so the `ORDER BY` clause, in your case, is irrelevant and could be removed.

> 3. what does it mean to include a constant ('XMEG') in the partition / order by. I'm guessing it will have no effect?

In this case, it has no effect.

You can do `COUNT(*) OVER ()` if you want to count over the entire result set without any partitions. If you wanted to include a `PARTITION BY` clause and still get the same effect then you could use `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 'a constant')` but that is about the only reason I can think to include a constant (and even then you could just omit the `PARTITION BY` clause).

Comment: @TheImpaler I've added a paragraph about that - but you're wrong as the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses are identical so all the rows in each partition will have identical order precedence within that partition so the `ORDER BY` clause could be removed and there would be no effect.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to give such a detailed response...and to the others for their useful contributions.